# get Actual content from a file from ContentDocumentId

Tags: files, contentversion, contentdocument

I have written a query i.e :

```
List<ContentVersion> contentversion = [SELECT VersionData,ContentBodyId,ContentDocumentId FROM ContentVersion WHERE Title =:customLabel];
```

Here I am getting all the Ids, and version data in BLOB type. Now I am not getting how to get the actually fetch the version data in the String.

Please provide suggestions on this. Thank you for your time!! :)

Comment: Do you mean convert the blob to a string?  Have you looked at [the documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_blob.htm)?  But please [edit] your question to explain why you need to do that.

Answer (score 2):

VersionData is a Blob, whether it can be converted to a string depends on the type of file. If it is a text file you can use [Blob.toString()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_blob.htm#apex_System_Blob_toString). If it is a binary file you can use functions from [EncodingUtil](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_classes_restful_encodingUtil.htm#apex_classes_restful_encodingutil) to get the contents as a base64 of hex encoded string, provided the encoded data is no more than the maximum string size in apex (6000000 bytes).

Comment: N.B. `Blob.toString()` assumes input is exclusively UTF-8

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example you could use for supporting ContentDocuments with FileType `TEXT`. Storing each `ContentDocument` and their respective `VersionData` as a `String` across a `Map`.

```
List<String> fileTypes = new List<String>{'TEXT'};
List<ContentVersion> contentVersions = [
    SELECT VersionData,ContentBodyId,ContentDocumentId
    FROM ContentVersion
    WHERE FileType in :fileTypes];

Map<ContentVersion, String> versionDataToContentVersion = new Map<ContentVersion, String>();

for (ContentVersion cv : contentVersions) {
    Blob versionDataBlob = cv.VersionData;
    String versionDataString = versionDataBlob.toString();
    versionDataToContentVersion.put(cv, versionDataString);
}
```